# What is the right Syntax of this JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have two tables (JPA entities)

1. JOB
2. APPLICANTS

JOBID is the common column between these two tables.
I am trying to select Job entities for which user has applied (Applicants table has userId field)

```
SELECT j from JOB j, APPLICANTS a WHERE j.jobId=:a.jobId AND a.userId=:userId
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

This throws the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT j from JOB j, APPLICANTS a WHERE j.jobId=:a.jobId AND a.uuId=:uuId]. 
[50, 58] The named input parameter ''{0}'' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
```

Comment: why would you reuse an alias name ("a") as a named parameter "name" ("a") ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to prefix the field value in `WHERE` with `:`, it is used only for parameters. So, if you want to join `Job`s and `Applicant`s on `jobId`, use this

```
SELECT j from JOB j, APPLICANTS a WHERE j.jobId = a.jobId AND a.userId = :userId
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

And if you want to pass `jobId` as a parameter, use this

```
SELECT j from JOB j, APPLICANTS a WHERE j.jobId = :jobId AND a.userId = :userId
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
query.setParameter("jobId", jobId);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the relationship between Job and  Applicants entity  using Annotation in 
Applicants entity

```
@manyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@joinColumns(name="job_id", insertable=false , updatable=false)
private Job job ;
```

And Your query should be like this

```
select  NEW YourClass( Your Column List  ) from Applicants a left join a.job where j.jobId=?1 and a.userId=?2

query.setParameter(1, userId);
query.setParameter(2, jobId);
```